# Inclusion Exclusion Principle (Probability) Problem: What is P(Rain)?

Tags: probability

If the probability that it will rain today A is 60%. The probability that it will rain tomorrow is 50% and the probability that it will not rain today nor tomorrow is 30%. Then:

What is the probability that it will rain today or tomorrow?

Why can't I say that the first two events are disjoint and that by the inclusion/exclusion principle, P(both events) = 110% ? Is it because that the sum of the probability is > 1 that we conclude that, based on the question, they aren't disjoint?

Comment: Well you have find the complement of the P(won't rain today and tomorrow) which is the same as 1-P(it will rain today or tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the events $A_1=${rain today} and $A_2=${rain tomorrow}. So we have $A_1\cup A_2=${rain today or tomorrow} and $A_1\cap A_2=${rain today and tomorrow}. So the event {not rain today nor tomorrow} is $\overline{A_1\cup A_2}$.

We find $$\mathbb{P}(A_1\cup A_2)=1-\Bbb{P}\left(\overline{A_1\cup A_2}\right)=1-0.3=0.7$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the "Inclusion-Exclusion" principle:

$$
1{}={}P\left(\mbox{Rain Today}\right){}+{}P\left(\mbox{Rain Tomorrow}\right) - P\left(\mbox{Rain both days}\right) + P\left(\mbox{No rain}\right)\,.
$$

Upon solving for "$P\left(\mbox{Rain both days}\right)$", then,

$$
P\left(\mbox{Rain Today or Tomorrow}\right){}={}P\left(\mbox{Rain Today}\right){}+{}P\left(\mbox{Rain Tomorrow}\right) - P\left(\mbox{Rain both days}\right)
$$